# play framework sometimes failed to read language files

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.3

I use playframework 2.3.x and have Russian and English languages. The problem is that the email sometimes can get the values from the language files.

For example, in the file, i have mail.subject=welcome to our platform.  it sometimes just sent the "mail.subject" instead of "welcome to our platform". Please advise how to solve this problem?

```
def sendEmail(to: String) {
try {
  var fromAddress = current.configuration.getString("smtp.from").get
  val bcc = current.configuration.getString("smtp.bcc").get
  val email = Email(
    Messages.get(getLan(), "mail.subject"),
    fromAddress,
    Seq(to),
    bodyHtml = Some(views.html.custom.mails.application().toString()),
    bcc = Seq(bcc)
  )
  MailerPlugin.send(email)
} catch {
  case ex: Exception => PlayLogger.instance.error(ex.getMessage)
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean failed? it sends message in another language?

Comment: It doesn't get the value at all.in the language file i have mail.subject=welcome to our platform. However, it just sent the "mail.subject".

Comment: no errors are logged during that behaviour?

Comment: There is no any error in the log file.

Comment: without additional it will be highly unlikely, that anybody could help. for example, i never had this problem at all. when it happening? could you identify cases? is it happening locally or on the server?

Answer (score 0):

`mail.subject` key is not defined for some language that you use, and that language is set in the request cookie.

Play, by default, take language from the cookie. The default language is selected if no language in a cookie was found or that language is not acceptable.

```
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Controller.scala#L64
```

You can fix it by set the language explicitly or create your own language detection.